# Difference between CBOW and Skipgram gradients in word2vec?

Tags: c++, nlp, word2vec

Why are `f` values that are greater than or lower than `MAX_EXP` taken into account during the updates in CBOW, but ignored in Skipgram?

I'm specifically looking at the Google implementation of word2vec, but the same functionality has been replicated throughout many other projects, one of which is [here](https://github.com/dav/word2vec/blob/master/src/word2vec.c), for larger context.

```
// CBOW negative sampling gradient calculations  
f = 0;
l2 = target * layer1_size;
for (c = 0; c < layer1_size; c++) f += neu1[c] * syn1neg[c + l2];
// ** here, we still update, but essentially round the value to 1 or 0
if (f > MAX_EXP) g = (label - 1) * alpha;
else if (f < -MAX_EXP) g = (label - 0) * alpha;
else g = (label - expTable[(int)((f + MAX_EXP) * (EXP_TABLE_SIZE / MAX_EXP / 2))]) * alpha;

// ---------------------------

// Skipgram hierarchical softmax gradient calculations
f = 0;
l2 = vocab[word].point[d] * layer1_size;
for (c = 0; c < layer1_size; c++) f += syn0[c + l1] * syn1[c + l2];
// ** here, we don't update if f is outside the range given by MAX_EXP **
if (f <= -MAX_EXP) continue;
else if (f >= MAX_EXP) continue;
else f = expTable[(int)((f + MAX_EXP) * (EXP_TABLE_SIZE / MAX_EXP / 2))];
g = (1 - vocab[word].code[d] - f) * alpha;
```